# Paypal sandbox close button issue

Tags: paypal

I integrated Paypal Adaptive Payments and I am currently testing it in sandbox mode. When I click pay button, it successfully pay and show the below screen. If I do not click the close button, it is automatically return back to my site with successful transaction.
But If I click the "CLOSE" button, it ask me to pay again and when I pay again, it will show an error with return button. If I click to return button, it will successfully return back to my site.

Please See this, http://awesomescreenshot.com/01947f0w1d

Most probably users will click the close button, and they do not want to pay again. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

Thanks
Asim